# Laravel Nova Metrics Partition belongsToMany relationship

Tags: laravel, metrics, laravel-nova

I have the following data model:

(Publication) <-[belongsToMany]-> (Subscriber)

I want to create a Nova Partition Metric to display the number of Subscribers for each Publication.

The calculate method of my Partition class looks like this:

`public function calculate(Request $request)
{
        return $this->count($request, Subscriber::with('publications'), 'publication.id');
}`

But I am getting an "unknown column" error. Anyone know how to make this work?

Comment: Isn't Nova a system you have to purchase? If so, doesn't it come with support?

Comment: The third parameter should be `publications.id`

Answer (score 5):

You could do something like this:

```php
public function calculate(Request $request)
{
    $subscribers = Subscriber::withCount('publications')->get();

    return $this->result(
        $subscribers->flatMap(function ($subscriber) {
            return [
                $subscriber->name => $subscriber->publications_count
            ];
        })->toArray()
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The count helper only allows to group by a column on model's table. It also don't allow to join tables.

If you want a more complex query, with a join and a group by column in another table, you can build your own array of results and return it with the results helper.

You can see the results helper docs here: https://nova.laravel.com/docs/1.0/metrics/defining-metrics.html#customizing-partition-colors

You should create your array (you can use eloquent or query builder here) inside the calculate function, then return that array with the results helper.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can make the groupBy on publication_foreign_key in Subscriber table and edit the publication_foreign_key to publication_name using ->label() method

Like this

```
       public function calculate(Request $request)
    {
       return $this->count($request, Subscriber::class, 'publication_id')
          ->label(function($publicationId) 
            {
            switch($publicationId)
             {
             case publication_foreign_key_1 : return publication_name_1;
                                  break;
             case publication_foreign_key_2 : return publication_name_2;
                                  break;
             default: return 'Others';
             }                 
           });
    }
```